# EC2 Multi App Instance - Some Ports not Reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, port, firewall

I have started an AWS EC2 (UBUNTU 18 AMI) instance running three apps:

- Web server on port 80
- REST API on port 8786
- DB on port X

I am able to

- SSH into the instance
- Reach the website via browser on port 80.
- Reach the REST API from within the SSH session.

I am unable to

- Reach the REST API via AJAX from the browser (tried postman as well).

I have

- Configured the Security Group to receive inbound connections from all sources on 8786
- verified that iptable is not loaded
- Tried reaching the website from a mobile network - to no avail.
- Swapped the ports between the Web Server and the REST API - which resulted in being able to access the API via the browser and postman.
- Verified that the API is bound to 0.0.0.0 - not to localhost.

This smells like an EC2 issue, but I have no idea what to do.

Help would be much appreaciated.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Have you tried doing telnet?

Comment: @MohitKumar on chrome: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". On postman: could not reach ... basically, unreachable.

Comment: @MohitKumar did not try telnet.. anything specific you suggest? I did manage to SSH into the instance ..

Comment: Try to do telnet from client(your machine): telnet hostip hostport suggestive answer: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server

Comment: @MohitKumar .Could not open connection to the host, on port 8786: Connect failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, 8786 is a reserved port, and should not be used. Issues were resolved when I changed to 8080, which I should have done in the very beginning.

Comment: Reserved by who?  There are no magic ports in EC2 that I am aware of.

Comment: Something called msgclnt. It is a sort of magiic, tbh. Despite being able to bind, nmap claimed something called msgclnt was running on the port, not my app. Contrary to netstat. Simply changing the app port and security group resolved the issue.

Comment: You will find that nmap was not claiming to have identified what was running... it was just telling you what name is assigned to that port for TCP.  8786 is `msgclnt` ("message client")... no different than 25 is named `smtp` and 80 is named `http`.   The `/etc/services` file lists many of these, as does https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml.  I don't know why your service didn't work on the alternate port, but I suspect there was a gap overlooked somewhere in the troubleshooting process, rather than an EC2 constraint. Your ISP, maybe?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I do not doubt what you said about nmap. I am fairly new to linux ( Never had an issue with port 8786 on the windows dev machine) .. in any case.. I did not confer with anyone on the ISP side of things.. I have also tried this again and again - 8786 seems to be a bad port in my specific instance.. do not know what to tell you other than that.